# Publish Word Add-in as individual

Tags: ms-word, office-addins, office-store, appsource

Due to the documentation on MS I was told, that it's possible to publish a `word-addin` (reactjs) to AppSource as a registered Microsoft Developer.

But once I try to setup "Office Store" in my partner center/developer dashboard, I´am requested to enter my business/company email and furthermore I´am required to have a registered company. What can I do to publish the add-in to AppSource/market?

Does anyone has experience with publishing add-ins to AppSource or publishing add-ins in general (as an individual)?
Thank you!